# Migration from Spring boot 2.X to 3.0.5 , spring batch 5.0.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-boot-3

i am trying to migrate spring boot 2.X to 3.0.5 and my spring batch is 2.0.1 .For that i changed my code from this

```
@Configuration @Slf4j public class DefaultBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    @Override public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {}
```

to this

@Configuration @Slf4j public class DefaultBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {}

PS: Dint find an alternative for setDataSource here

but now when i run the application i get an error saying following stack trace
PS : This is rough stacktrace as i cant put complete stack trace here due to my personal laptop

ERROR SpringApplication Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'manualJobExecutor': Unsatisfied dependency express through field scheduleService: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency through field 'jobs': Error.....Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerServiceImpl': Caused by: error creating bean with name 'jobRepository'
defined in class path resource[DefaultBatchConfig.class]

and below is my scheduler service impl class

```
@Service @Slf4j public class SchedulerServiceImpl implements SchedulerService {
    @Autowired private Map < String, JobExecutor > jobs;
    @Override @Async(value = "asyncPool") public void executeJob(JobParam job) {
        ExecutorService executorService = jobExecutor - > jobExecutor.execute(job);
        executorService.execute(jobs.get(job.getName()));
    }
```

}

I tried running the spring boot application and it fails with the above error is there anything i am missing in the migration or in the codee if not whats the issue

Comment: Any other bean other than jobRepository bean is configured in DefaultBatchConfig class got created?

Comment: @Dil1y_reddy doesnt look like it ...coz i get error creating bean even for jobLauncher bean in defaultBatchConfig . There is a lot of 'caused by' in my stack trace

Comment: By any chance, you missed @EnableBatchProcessing to add?

Comment: No its added in my spring boot application class..but isnt @EnableBatchProcessing not needed in spring batch 5 anyways ? also is there any alternative to this setDataSource  method in spring batch 5 ? coz i dont see any data source being setup without it ...